# PSRR in LDO system

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, ldo

I have a question about PSRR.

For example, in an LDO PMOS structure why can we increase the PSRR if the output capacitor is the dominant pole? Generally, for ICs, we prefer to not use big capacitors at the output but I'm just curious to understand why if the output capacitor is big we increase the PSRR.

I also know that this capacitor will act as a filter but that means, for example, we don't consider this big output capacitor during loop analysis. If we consider this output capacitor we will have a very small BW and so a bad PSRR at high frequency.

I'm a bit muddled. Could you explain this to me if you are able?

[image: ldo pmos ans nmos structure]

Comment: Please link the source of the assertion you are making (*why can we increase the PSRR if the output capacitor is the dominant pole?*)

Comment: Hi, in this video , from 29mn to the end of the video (34mn), but exactly at 32mn:38 ... thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output cap is definitely to be considered in loop analysis and yes, if it is too large, it will reduce the loop bandwidth. Please find below the explanation of why increasing output cap in an output dominant pole scenario helps improve PSRR.

For PMOS output transistor LDO where the dominant pole is the output pole, I have shown 2 cases in the below plot (load current = 0 in both cases). Clearly in the higher cap scenario, the PSRR is better.

[image]

In my simulation, non-dominant pole is at 1.2MHz & DC gain is at 66dB
In 1nF output cap case, the dominant pole is at 1.6kHz
In 10nF output cap case, the dominant pole is at 160Hz

1. For frequencies upto the dominant pole, PSRR between both cases is the same as the loop gain is the same and the output pole magnitude is dominated by the resistor divider
2. For frequencies between the dominant pole and the UGB, gain drops at 20dB/decade and output pole magnitude also drops at 20dB/decade. The former will worsen the PSRR and the latter improves the PSRR and in total, they cancel each other leading to a flat PSRR till the UGB.
3. For frequencies higher than the UGB, there is no gain practically and hence PSRR is fully dependent on the ratio of output pole magnitude to the PMOS ROUT. So, the PSRR starts dropping due to the output pole magnitude drop (due to the load cap)

**In summary, the load cap increase only helps improve PSRR at higher frequencies (beyond UGB). Though UGB reduces because of load cap increase, it does not worsen the PSRR because the output impedance is also dropping and they cancel each other.**

Comment: Perfect, thank you for this well detailed explanation

Comment: You could choose to accept the answer if you wish. Please see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Isn't 1/10nF really small for an LDO output capacitor? Most I've seen require microfarads to be stable, and some recommend 3-4 orders of magnitude larger than that.

Comment: @user1850479, the capacitors used in my simulation were only to illustrate the concept. Also, the LDO I used was a custom LDO designed by me so that I know where the poles lie. If you are using a discrete LDO IC, you definitely need to use the cap that the datasheet recommends.